# Why is `pip3 install numpy` much faster than setting it in `install_requires`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip, setuptools

The following takes place in a Python 3 virtual environment.

I just authored a little package that requires `numpy`. So, in `setup.py`, I wrote `install_requires=['numpy']`. I ran `python3 setup.py install`, and it took something like two minutes -- I got the full screen dump of logs, warnings, and configurations that normally comes with a numpy installation.

Then, I created a new virtual environment, and this time simply wrote `pip3 install numpy` -- which took only a few seconds -- and then ran `python3 setup.py install`, and I was done almost immediately.

What's the difference between the two, and why was `pip3 install numpy` so much faster? Should I thus include a `requirements.txt` just so people can pip-install the requirements rather than using setuptools?

---

Note that when I wrote `pip3 install numpy`, I got the following:

```
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.12.0
```

Is it possible that this was so much faster because the numpy wheel was already cached?

Comment: Using **cached** numpy?

Comment: @McGrady Yeah, I'm assuming that this has the wheel cached, not the actual installation itself. When I install numpy using setuptools, only a few seconds are spent on the download -- the rest of the time is spent on the installation.

Comment: If you try to install your package in a new venv, is it now faster than it was the first time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip install` uses `wheel` packages, which were designed partly with the purpose of speeding up the installation process.

The [Rationale](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#rationale) section of [PEP 427](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/), which introduced the `wheel` format, states:

> Python needs a package format that is easier to install than sdist.
>   Python's sdist packages are defined by and require the distutils and
>   setuptools build systems, running arbitrary code to build-and-install,
>   and re-compile, code just so it can be installed into a new
>   virtualenv. This system of conflating build-install is slow, hard to
>   maintain, and hinders innovation in both build systems and installers.
>
> Wheel attempts to remedy these problems by providing a simpler
>   interface between the build system and the installer. The wheel binary
>   package format frees installers from having to know about the build
>   system, saves time by amortizing compile time over many installations,
>   and removes the need to install a build system in the target
>   environment.

Installing from a `wheel` is faster since it is a [Built Distribution format](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-built-distribution):

> **Built Distribution**
>
> A Distribution format containing files and metadata that only need to be moved to the correct location on the target system, to be
>   installed. Wheel is such a format, whereas distutil’s Source
>   Distribution is not, in that it requires a build step before it can be
>   installed. This format does not imply that python files have to be
>   precompiled (Wheel intentionally does not include compiled python
>   files).

Since `numpy`'s source distribution contains significant amount of C code, compiling it takes noticeable time, which you observed when you installed it via bare `setuptools`. pip avoided the compilation of C code since the wheel came with binary code (already compiled for your system).